# gcloud command line client - working on multiple gCloud projects in parallel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

We are using Jenkins to build and push data to Google Cloud Storage.

We have a single build machine; and multiple different Google Projects (testing; production)

If there are parallel builds being done by the 'jenkins' user on 1 build node; is there any way to pass parameters to `gcloud docker -- push` so that separate credentials authenticate one push to the `testing` Google Project and the other to the `production` project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options here, from a Cloud SDK standpoint.

The first one is to use different configuration directories. By default, the Cloud SDK uses `~/.config/gcloud` as its configuration directory; the `$CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` environment variable overrides this. It's effectively the same as having two different installs if you use different configuration directories, and you don't run any risk of e.g. race conditions.

The second one is to use [named configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations). This is probably easiest to illustrate with an example:

```
$ gcloud config configurations create foo  # creates and activates a new configuration
$ gcloud auth login  # you may want to use `activate-service-account` for non-interactive use
$ gcloud config set project foo-project
$ gcloud config configurations create bar
$ gcloud auth login
$ gcloud config set project bar-project
$ CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=foo gcloud version &
$ CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=bar gcloud version &
```

If you just want to change on configuration property, you can do so via the environment variable `$CLOUDSDK_<SECTION>_<PROPERTY>`. For instance, `$CLOUDSDK_CORE_ACCOUNT` or `$CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT`. For some common flags, you can set them on every gcloud command: `--project` or `--account`, for instance. See [gcloud help](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) for an overview of these common flags.

That said, with `gcloud docker` you'll probably run into an issue in any of these cases, since `docker` shares one configuration file. Your best bet is probably to use [docker-credential-gcr](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr) with different `$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` files.